# Clear "Always open in .." container preference for a specific site

Tags: firefox, multi-account-containers

I have a Container named AbcContainer in my Firefox. Lets say, by mistake, I opt for a specific site (say http://example.org) to always open in that container. How do I go about clearing this preference, so that site http://example.org opens in Default Container going forward?

I get the below prompt, when opening http://example.org from Default Container. But, checking the "Remember my decision" checkbox and choosing "Open in Current Container" doesn't yield the desired results.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a site from its default Firefox container](https://superuser.com/questions/1574156/remove-a-site-from-its-default-firefox-container)

Answer (score 31):

1. Open the website from within the container you want to remove it from.
2. Right-click on the container icon to the right of the URL in the address bar.
3. Uncheck the submenu item "Always open in this container"

Comment: There's no such option for me.

Comment: @AshBerlin-Taylor For some reason, it doesn't always appear. I thought it was a bug for me.

Comment: I know this is an old question (and answer), but I just had the same problem and just in case it helps someone: The container submenu only appeared for me when I opened the page in the container that I wanted to remove it from. @Flimm, maybe add that detail to your answer so it's more visible?

Comment: Yes, I was also not able to see the option. But when opened the page in the container that I wanted to remove it from, then the tick was visible.

Comment: Check if you are within the "always" container to show this option. It's not showed in normal tab or others containers.

Comment: I must admit, that was not intuitive to find.

Comment: It didn't show up when right clicking on the page, but i found it by right clicking on the container icon in the address bar while on the page

Comment: This doesn't work if it is set on a redirected page, in that case prefer: https://superuser.com/a/1703330/967249

Answer (score 16):

There is an option to configure in Container's management panel   [manage lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjn3l.png)

1. Open Containers add-on
2. Click "Manage Containers"
3. Choose the container you want to manage
4. Click "Manage Site List..."

Now you are able to remove the sites.

Answer (score 11):

Finally found it by following [@Xinyu](https://superuser.com/a/1703330/84963) steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a proper, official way. Should be an accepted answer.

Comment: Worked for me too, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way, it's kind of tricky but it's work :)

1. Create new container as "temp"
2. Select always open this site in "temp" container
3. open site in another container
   => tick remember my choice to make sure site always open in "temp" container without asking
4. remove temp container in setting ( about:preferences#containers )

Done :)