# Remove a site from its default Firefox container

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have many Firefox containers I use for multiple sites at work.  By mistake I added my SSO provider page to a container `FOO`, which is intended for other usage.

Now every time I request from my SSO provider to open one of my intranet sites, Firefox asks me if I want to open it in `FOO` or in the default container and if I want to remember my decision.  It takes time to tell it *not* to open it in `FOO` and it does *not remember* my decision as the addresses from the SSO provider change every time I follow the link.

Is there any way of removing a single website from its default container (I this case from `FOO` to the default non-container)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a way to do this without dropping the container.  You must go to the `Multi-account container` button in the top bar, then click to *manage containers*, then click the container where the wrong site was added by default.

Then there is a button named *manage site list* and there you can (obviously) remove sites from being defaulted to that container.

Comment: I'd never had found that. Thanks!

Comment: I just verified in Firefox 100.0 on MacOS that the option is still there.  Which version / operating system are you using?

Comment: thank you!! i was going nuts..

Comment: It took me also a while and some frustration to find the `Multi-account container` button. Be aware, it is not the button in the address bar.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! - I've seen that manage-container list before, but it never occurred to me that you could click the containers for more options, I thought you could only rearrange their order. Gotta love that utterly garbage UI/UX, huh? 

Comment: Make sure you click on "Limit to designated sites". Containers are such a broken-ass feature of Firefox.

Comment: Why broken? You have some reference/link that talks about the problem you mention?

Comment: I couldn't find the _Multi-account container button in the top bar_ so I found my way there by clicking the "all tabs" button in the top right corner (looks like a "down arrow/chevron" icon to the right of the "new tab" button with a "plus" icon). Then "New container tab" then "Manage containers".

Comment: @Dawngerpony And I don't see "manage site list" if I go your way. And original way I see "manage site list but clicking it shows empty window . Seems  a bug.